# link creation and canvas download Image work ONLY ONE TIME in Chrome

Tags: javascript, image, file, canvas, blob

I created javascript tool that reads a photo from an input field, modifies it, resizes it and displays it on the page in an tag. Then I create a link and start the download automatically. 
Everything works perfectly with Firefox, Opera, Safari, but work ONLY ONE TIME in Chrome! (not working all in IE,but is not a problem for me. Any idea?

https://jsfiddle.net/tuttoeniente/efod3avh/1/

**EDIT:** 

*ONLY ONE TIME*, I mean after opening the browser. If I close the browser, open it again, the cache will work. Everything works fine, the second time the photo is generated correctly, but it is not downloaded automatically.

```
function downloadCanvas() {
    if (datoImg !== undefined) {
        if (!isChrome && !isIE) {
            //funziona per firefox, safari ed opera
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.href = datoImg;
            link.download = getNomeFoto();
            link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window}));
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        } else{
            //converte in blob, altrimenti chrome non codificava bene
            dataURIToBlob(datoImg, callback);
        }
    } else {
        alert("Niente da scaricare");
    }
}


function dataURIToBlob(dataURI, callback) {
    var binStr = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]),
            len = binStr.length,
            arr = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = binStr.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    callback(new Blob([arr]));
}

//funzione utilizzata per chrome che genera link
var callback = function (blob) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.download = getNomeFoto();
    a.innerHTML = 'download';
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true, cancelable: true, view: window}));
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what "only one time" means? What happens after that? An error? No actions? Something else?

Comment: Does it alert `Niente da scaricare` the second time on chrome?

Comment: ONLY ONE TIME the link download, I mean after opening the browser. If I close the browser, open it again, the cache will work. Everything works fine, the second time the photo is generated correctly, but it is not downloaded automatically.

Comment: The alert serves as a control, I only pasted the part of code inherent to this problem but the app is more complex.